# Javascript not running on page load...but with Firebug it does run?

Tags: javascript, ajax, graph

I have a little pretend sales graph that using the Envision.js library.  It works great as long as Firebug is running.  It will graph a number between 20-25 and when I turn the web server off it flatlines at 0.  But if I turn off firebug, then refresh; all it does is flatline at zero.  It's got to have something to do with the placement of my ajax function: myFunction(), but I have no idea what.  Could someone please give me an eyeball on this?  I'm just not seeing anything.  I do know it's not the Ajax functions itself as I'm using the exact same two functions on another page and they work perfect.  I'm getting (4 & 200) back from the server so I have no idea...Thanks in advance.

```
//Global Variables//////////



var counter = 0;
var myArray = [25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20];
var resultToGraph;
var url = "http://myserver.com/ajax_info.txt";
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc(url, cfunc)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(){
    loadXMLDoc(url+'?_dc='+(new Date()).getTime(), function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
             resultToGraph  = myArray[Math.floor((Math.random()*5))];
    }
        else{
            resultToGraph = 0;
        }
    });
}

(function realtime_demo (container) {

  var
    x = [],
    dataA = [],
    data = [[x, dataA]],
    options, i, timesries;

  // Mock Data:
    function sample(i) {    
    x.push(i);
    dataA.push(i);  
    }

  // Initial Data:
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    sample(i);
    }

  // Envision Timeseries Options
    options = {
    container : container,
    data : {
        detail : data,
        summary : data
    },
    defaults : {
        summary : {
        config : {
            colors : [ 'red'], //added to code...nothing there initiall**
            handles : { show : true } //changed from false **   
        }
        }
    }
    }

  // Render the timeseries
    timeseries = new envision.templates.TimeSeries(options);

  // Method to get new data
  // This could be part of an Ajax callback, a websocket callback,
  // or streaming / long-polling data source.
    function getNewData () {
    i++;

    // Short circuit (no need to keep going!  you get the idea)
    if (i > 5000) return;
    sample(i);
    animate(i);
    }

  // Initial request for new data
    getNewData();

  // Animate the new data
    function animate (i) {

      var
    start = (new Date()).getTime(),
    length = 500, // 500ms animation length
    max = i - 1,  // One new point comes in at a time
    min = i - 31, // Show 50 in the top
    offset = 0;   // Animation frame offset

    // Render animation frame
    (function frame () {

         var
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            tick = Math.min(time - start, length),
        offset = 0;
            //offset = (Math.sin(Math.PI * (tick) / length - Math.PI / 2) + 1) / 2;

      // Draw the summary first
        timeseries.summary.draw(null, {
        xaxis : {
            min : 0,
            max : max + offset
        }
        });

      // Trigger the select interaction.
      // Update the select region and draw the detail graph.
        timeseries.summary.trigger('select', {
        data : {
            x : {
            min : min + offset,
            max : max + offset
            }
        }
        });

        if (tick < length) {
        setTimeout(frame, 0);
        } else {
        // Pretend new data comes in every second
        setTimeout(getNewData, 0);
        }
    })();
    }
}
)(document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: Not familiar with "Envision.js library" but with some Google scripts there can be an issue of trying to run it too quickly after linking to it.  Have you tried putting in a short delay before using it?

Comment: That's not the problem as when I'm running Firebug...the javascript seems to perform perfectly.  But when I turn it off and refresh...it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Firebug forces the script to slow down, which may give it the time it needs to connect properly.

Comment: well that's not the problem

Comment: Where is myFunction() called?

Comment: Currently I"m calling it right at the beginning of the function: function getNewData().  I have a global called resultsToGraph that I have put in place of the  dataA.push(Math.sin(i / 6) * (Math.random() + 1) / 2);.....so dataA.push(resultsToGraph).    In case anyone isn't familiar with Envision:  http://humblesoftware.com/envision/demos/realtime